# Eclipse RCP E4 switch perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have two plugins A and B, for each plugin it will have its own `Perspective` or `Views`. Now I'd like to switch from one perspective (A) to another (B) and expect that the `Menu` and its submenus (or `Handled Menu Item`) changes based on what I have configured in the plugin B `e4xmi` file.

How do I ensure a set of menus are only loaded for a given perspective ? Do I really have to use the `Core Expression` ?

**UPDATE**

I declared a set of menus for plugin A in `Application.e4xmi`. While the set up for plugin B is in `fragment.e4xmi`.

This is the definition I created in the plugin B. However I am not seeing the menu in any of the perspective.

```
    <extension
         point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
      <definition
            id="com.amap.ui.active.perspective">
          <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
            <equals value="amap.ui.perspective.ui">
            </equals>
        </with>
      </definition>
    </extension>
```

Comment: I don't see any alternative.

Comment: can you show me the usage of core expression ? Perhaps the portion where it check if current perspective id is equals to `com.myapp.plugin.a` then only show the menus. Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like it may be necessary to use a property tester as 'activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective' is not valid in e4. [This blog entry](http://jonathanjwright.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/eclipse-4-4-0-perspective-based-show-hide-of-tool-bar-items/) covers this.